# Adding season factor based on Date in R

Tags: r

How can i add season as factor depending on dates in R?  I have a table with dates of 4 years and  i have to add a column season which will look at the month and day of date and decide which season it is. I am taking some fixed dates for each season irrespective of the year.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data? This is pretty straightfoward, but the precise solution will depend on what your data look like. Perhaps give us the output of `dput(head(df))`, where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: @user2563925 please let me know if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `quarter()` from `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- structure(c(15238, 15730, 15362, 15478, 15764, 15635, 15372, 
                     15768, 15243, 15377), class = "Date") # example data
dates
# > dates
# [1] "2011-09-21" "2013-01-25" "2012-01-23" "2012-05-18" "2013-02-28" "2012-10-22" "2012-02-02"
# [8] "2013-03-04" "2011-09-26" "2012-02-07"
dates <- as.data.frame(dates)
dates$q <- quarter(dates$dates)
# dates q
# 1  2011-09-21 3
# 2  2013-01-25 1
# 3  2012-01-23 1
# 4  2012-05-18 2
# 5  2013-02-28 1
# 6  2012-10-22 4
# 7  2012-02-02 1
# 8  2013-03-04 1
# 9  2011-09-26 3
# 10 2012-02-07 1
dates$season <- NA # If you really want seasons (string) proceed...
dates <- within(dates, {season[q == 1] <- "spr"
                        season[q == 2] <- "sum"
                        season[q == 3] <- "fall"
                        season[q == 4] <- "win"})
# dates q season
# 1  2011-09-21 3   fall
# 2  2013-01-25 1    spr
# 3  2012-01-23 1    spr
# 4  2012-05-18 2    sum
# 5  2013-02-28 1    spr
# 6  2012-10-22 4    win
# 7  2012-02-02 1    spr
# 8  2013-03-04 1    spr
# 9  2011-09-26 3   fall
# 10 2012-02-07 1    spr
```